# TS unable to infer type definition based on another parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to limit the possible values of second parameter, depending on the value of first parameter but failed to do so

**Approach 1: Function overloading**

```
export function printProfileByType(
  type: 't1',
  payload: { name: string }
): string;
export function printProfileByType(
  type: 't2',
  payload: { age: number }
): string;
export function printProfileByType(
  type: 't1' | 't2',
  payload: { name: string } | { age: number }
): string {
  if (type === 't1') {
    console.log(payload.name); // Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ name: string; } | { age: number; }'. Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ age: number; }'
  }
  return '';
}
```

Seems like despite there is a check `if (type === 't1')`, TS is still not able to tell that payload is certain to be only of type `{name: string}`?

My second approach was to go by using generic but same error occurred as well

**Approach 2: Generics**

```js
type FunctionParams = {
   t1: { name: string };
   t2: { age: number };
};

export function PrintName<T extends keyof FunctionParams>(
   type: T,
   payload: FunctionParams[T]
 ) {
   if (type === 't1') {
     console.log(payload.name); // Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ name: string; } | { age: number; }'. Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ age: number; }'
   } else if (type === 't2') {
     console.log(payload.age); // Property 'age' does not exist on type '{ name: string; } | { age: number; }'. Property 'age' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'.
   }
 }
```

Comment: In both cases, there's an "overload" where `type` is `"t1" | "t2"`, and `payload` is `{ name: string } | { age: number }` *independently* of that, which is what matters in the function body.

Comment: What about using a type guard instead?

Comment: @Isaac actually, it should. Something like this should be enough: `function objectIsTX<T extends keyof FunctionParams>(obj: any, k: T): obj is FunctionParams[T] {
  return Boolean(obj[k]);
}` and instead of checking type, you just do: `if (objectIsTX(payload, 't1')) {
    console.log(payload.name);
  }`

Comment: @briosheje: typeguard will only work if we guard against unique props, less elegant but should do the job

Comment: @Isaac AFAIK you cannot narrow the type of something by checking the value of something else.